# How can I increase the badge count on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I have only two badges on Stack Overflow. How do I increase this?

I have tried many things: I have asked questions, but they were disapproved. Is there another way to earn badges?

Comment: [Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=unearned) require [activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10780459/sujan-rai?tab=activity&sort=all) ...

Comment: Which badge are you trying to get. Why? How?

Comment: The easiest is [the Fanatic badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75171/100-consecutive-days-but-no-fanatic-badge) (a similar model is used on [LBRY](https://lbry.com/)).

Answer (score 4):

Go to your profile (button is in the top right).
Next to 'reputation' you will see 'badges'.
Click on the gear symbol next to 'Next Badge' to see what badges are available.
I think this will take you to your profile-
https://stackoverflow.com/users/10780459/sujan-rai